VScode extension problem：Extension is enabled on 'WSL: Ubuntu-18.04'
I cannot use the debug feature and I don't know why. I'm wondering if it is related to the Python extension. Many plugins display the message: "Extension is enabled on 'WSL: Ubuntu-18.04'." I am using VS Code connected to WSL for my operations.
how can I solve this problem? how can I debug in vscode?
enter image description here
enter image description here

please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors
And give us some context (language you are trying to debug etc...)
